# JS autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I used to use a guitar tab site and it had a feature where you'd be able to auto-scroll the page you were on.  There was a control panel that was fixed regardless of where on the page the screen was scrolled to which you could use to set the scroll speed and turn it off.     Now, I can't remember which site it was, nor can I find it again (I've found one which I'm pretty sure was it, but it doesn't have that feature, so they might've gotten rid of it, although I've no idea why they would've done that.

**My question is:**  I'd like to be able to replicate this in a greasemonkey script, preferably via jQuery for X-browser compatibility, so that it may be used on other sites with lyrics, tabs, and the sort.  How can I do that?  I'm setting this to community-wiki mode, so if anyone knows of/finds the site I'm talking about, just feel free to link to it for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this fit your needs?

[jQuery AutoScroll](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/AutoScroll/demo.php)

Comment: nope, don't think so, u'd need to specify targets all throughout the page, which don't exist.  I'd just like something that will "scroll down" at a constant, userdefined speed.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6515) designed for exactly this.